# How to remove negative part of the Sinusoidal function

Tags: real-analysis

Hi I have a general question. Is there a way that we could transform the negative part of a sinusoidal function to zero value. For example it should look like

[image: Text]
where only positive part of sinusoidal function retains.

for example the transformed $f(\sin(\omega t -k x))$ looks like

\begin{cases} 
      \sin(\omega t -k x) & \sin(\omega t - kx) > 0 \\
      0 &\sin(\omega t - kx) \leq 0 \\
   \end{cases}

Comment: $f(x) =\frac{x+|x|}{2}$ works

Comment: Sure, you have even defined a version of such a function right in your question. You could get a different expression for the function by for example considering it's fourier series or you could write it as $sinewave(t) \cdot squarewave(t)$ or something like that. What specifically do you not like about the way you've defined it?

Comment: @SV-97 The simpler the better. I know I can use some Fourier transform but I want to avoid the series and keep sinusoidal properity.